# Get value that contains double quotes

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set a variable to the value of an input using jQuery then append a new input with that value. The problem is that the value contains double quotes so it messes up the output.

Eg:

```
<input value="a:1:{s:7:&quot;form&quot;;a:5" />
<div class="test"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.test').append('<input type="radio" value="'+ value +'"/>');
```

Output:

```
<div class="test"><input value="a:1:{s:7:" form";a:5" type="radio"></div>
```

Comment: Why not use `$('input').val()`? Also, what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: It does work for me: https://fiddle.jshell.net/rkz9p67q/ Are you sure the problem isn't somewhere else?

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/shbkh69s/3/

Comment: You shouldn't have quotes in `console.log('value')`

Comment: @Barmar You're right, I have revised the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `"` as the delimiters arount the `value` attribute, and that character is also in the value that you're putting there. So those embedded quotes are ending the attribute.

Create the element using object syntax, rather than by concatenating strings, then you don't have to deal with these syntactic details.

```
$('.test').append($('<input>', {
    value: value
}));
```

You can also use the `.val()` function to set the value of the input:

```
$('.test').append($('<input>').val(value));
```